# ERROR: Running multiple emulators with the same AVD is an experimental feature for ubuntu in android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, ubuntu, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

I'm working on Android Studio version 3.5.1. I have created multiple emulators as per my requirements.
 Some emulators are working fine, but while running some another emulator, facing above raised issue as:

**ERROR: Running multiple emulators with the same AVD is an experimental feature.

        Emulator: Process finished with exit code 1**

Answer (score 16):

**Solution:**

```
In Ubuntu OS,
1. Go to Home --> press ctrl+h to visible hidden files

2. Open .android folder --> .avd folder --> Open your Device API specific folder
       For ex. for my device it was "Nexus_6P_API_22.avd" folder.

3. Delete below mentioned files: 
       a. multiinstance.lock
       b. hardware-qemu.ini.lock
       c. cache.img
```

Answer (score 4):

in addition, to Sanakhatun Shaikh answer delete

```
d. cache.img.qcow2
```